# Frozenset doesn't display its contents in Spyder Variable Explorer

Tags: python, machine-learning, spyder, apriori

After applying apriori algorithm to Market Basket Optimization data set when I open the rule in Spyder, instead of showing `frozenset({'light cream', 'chicken'})` shows `frozenset object of builtins module`

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Market_Basket_Optimisation.csv', header = None)
transactions = []
for i in range(0, 7501):
transactions.append([str(dataset.values[i,j]) for j in range(0, 20)])

# Train model
from apyori import apriori
rules = apriori(transactions, min_support = 0.003, min_confidence = 0.2, min_lift = 3, min_length = 2)

# To get the output 
results = list(rules)
```

[Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11aehhxy2tVeG6KXI3au82LV-0lnax7TE/view?usp=sharing)

Images for reference:

[First case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p1Zl.jpg)

[Second case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALGOd.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post image links of your code or data. On SO you have to post actual snippets of code or data inside the question. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you're going to have to debug a little for yourself We can't see the difference between those two objects in your IDE.

Comment: thanks for the reply.I have made some necessary changes to the post

Comment: Ok now we have code, but we don't have your dataset so we can't reproduce this and get whatever frozenset output you got. Can you generate some random-seeded data so we can reproduce on it?

Comment: Thank you for your patience.I have edited the post and attached the dataset link.

Comment: I tried the exact code in jupyter and it worked like a charm.I think the issue is with some settings in spyder since i am using spyder

Comment: I'm confused: is there a real difference between the code with and without Spyder, i.e. one fails and one works? If so please include a code snippet proving what fails under Spyder and why. Or is it merely cosmetic differences in viewing the output object in the IDE, but the code still works?

Comment: I'm sceptical this is a real issue because I see [337 issues about Spyder object](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spyder+object), so maybe it's just not a great IDE. Suggest you use either RStudio or Jupyter (or Zeppelin). Please confirm the issue is Spyder-only.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but yes as I mentioned earlier the issue is indeed with  the spyder.I tried the exact code in the Jupyter and it showed me the output i wanted.

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) *Short answer*: The reason for this problem is very simple: we don't support `frozenset`'s in our Variable Explorer. That's why they are not displayed unless you turn off the option called `Exclude unsupported data types`, and after that they are shown as generic objects.

*Long answer*: We can't simply use the `repr` of an object to display that in the Variable Explorer. That's because if your object is quite complex (i.e. it has too many elements or it's composed of objects with long `repr`'s), the Spyder console hangs trying to compute its `repr`. We learned that the hard way after many years of supporting complex scientific workflows.

So for each type object we need to decide how it's going to be displayed in the Variable Explorer. For example, we show Column names for Dataframes and the ten first elements of lists and dicts. We already have a small library to do that, but we need to expand it every time people wants to see new type objects.

*Note*: We plan to do that process extendible by plugins in Spyder 4 (to be released in 2019).

Comment: can you please tell me how to turn off Exclude unsupported data types?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a `print(results)`, because the Variable Explorer in Spyder does not support frozenset data types.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv("Market_Basket_Optimisation.csv",header=None)
transaction=[]
for i in range(0,7501):
    transaction.append([str(df.values[i,j]) for j in range(0,20)])

from apyori import apriori
rules = apriori(transaction, min_support = 0.003, min_confidence = 0.2, min_lift = 3, min_length = 2)

result=list(rules)

results=str(result)

frozensets=results.split("RelationRecord")
```

Answer (score -1):

To print each rule with a bit of separation in between, try"

```
for i in results:
    print(i)
    print('**********')
```